# When rendering a box with texture using a-frame, why does the console report cross-orgin error?

Tags: javascript

When rendering a box with texture using a-frame, the console reports

> "three.js:31187DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at
>   file:///E:/IT_Developer/Web_Developer/aframe-tutorial/FF4D00-0.8.png
>   may not be loaded."

The source code is simple as below:

```
 <a-scene>
   <a-assets>
     <img id="texture" src="FF4D00-0.8.png">
   </a-assets>
   <a-box color="#FFF" width="4" height="10" depth="2"
          position="-10 2 -5" rotation="0 0 45" scale="2 0.5 3"
          src="#texture"></a-box>
 </a-scene>
```

P.S. the image used is a single pixel png file.

Comment: Are you using Chrome to test? Try open it with the following command: chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Comment: Yes, I used chrome to test. It says `bash: chrome: command not found
`. Could you be more specific on this approach. Thx.

Comment: If you are using Windows, create a .bat file with the following commands:
cd C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security. Or simply go the Chrome folder and execute the command via prompt/terminal.

Comment: Thanks. It works good now.